# Undefined behavior of a c++ program

Tags: c++, c++14

I have listed 2 codes below

**CODE 1:**

```
int  main()
{       
int z=0 ,a[100];    
for(int i=10;i<=30;i++)
{
if(palindrome(i))
a[++z]=i;
}    
cout<<"value of z = "<<z<<endl;    
}
```

**CODE 2:**

```
int  main()
{
int z=0 ,a[100];

for(int i=10;i<=30;i++)
{
if(palindrome(i))
a[++z]=i;
cout<<z<<endl;   //  JUST ADDED THIS EXTRA LINE
}

cout<<"value of z = "<<z<<endl;
}
```

---

**#Note:**

the function palindrome return 0 if the number given is not a palindrome

*function palindrome is as follows*

```
int palindrome (int n)
{
    int rev;
    int n1=n;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        int t=n%10;
        rev = (rev*10) + t;
        n/=10;
    }
    
    if(rev!=n1)
    return 0;   
}
```

---

**OUTPUT FOR CODE 1:** `value of z = 0`

**OUTPUT FOR CODE 2:**

```
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
value of z = 2
```

can anyone explain why addition of  `cout<<z<<endl;` inside the loop creating such a drastic change in value of final z ?

**EDIT:**

*through comments for this question i realized that initializing `rev=0` in my palindrome function would sort the issue.
But Can anyone tell me why adding **cout<<z<<endl;** inside the loop  made a change in output ?*

Comment: 1/Your `rev` variable in the `palindrome` function is uninitialised. 2/ At the end of the `palindrome` function, if `rev == n1` the return value is not defined. This does not even compile for me with clang.

Comment: @op414 at the beginning of palindrome function i have initialized the value `rev` as `int rev;`

Comment: `int rev;` _declares_ `rev`, it does not _initalize_ it. To initialise to 0, write `int rev{};`

Comment: @op414  yeah doing `int rev=0;` made the change .......thanks a lot ......but can you explain me how ????

Comment: @op414   please let me knw how a small initialization to `0` made a change ????? that too in a function ...

Comment: C++ does not initialise variables automatically. When you write, `int rev;`, `rev` could be anything: it could be `0`, `1212`, or any other value. So when your program reaches `rev = (rev*10) + t;` your new `rev` value can be anything as well. This is of course going to alter what happens in your program. This is as you mentioned [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). When you have UB, weird things can happen, the program can behave the same 99% of the time, but sometimes differently, or just adding a line of code can alter the behaviour.

Comment: I suggest you use a modern compiler like MSVC, gcc or clang, and turn on all warnings (and read + understand them). This will catch this kinds of programming mistakes easily. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings) for more information.

Comment: `17:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` https://godbolt.org/z/Tf8s199fz

Comment: @godbolt.org/z/Tf8s199fz  in which compiler did you  get this error ?

Comment: @godbolt.org/z/Tf8s199fz  i guess adding `else  return 1 ;`  at end of palindrome function will sort this  issue ...

Comment: @SMaheshKumar you have confused link to online compiler with a user :)

Answer (score 1):

The code causes undefined behaviour:

- `rev` was used while uninitialized.
- `palindrome` can finish without executing a `return` statement, and the caller uses the return value.

The reason that a `cout` statement affects the behaviour could be that when the compiler reads the uninitialized storage , it happened to be in the same memory location as memory used by the `cout` call .  (You cannot rely on this)